# What's the difference between .on('click hover') or .on('click') and .on('hover')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I recently learned that you can add multiple events to the `.on()` method of `JQuery` to call the same function like this:

```js
var elmt = $('#myElmt');

elmt.on('click hover', myCallbackFunction);
```

Before I separate them like this:

```js
var elmt = $('#myElmt');

elmt.on('click', myCallbackFunction);
elmt.on('hover', myCallbackFunction);
```

Is there or have you ever fallen in a case where there's a difference between the two (e.g. constraints to make the code evolve, differences in performance, etc)?

Or is it exactly the same and only the taste of the developer can influence the choice?

Comment: You mean other than clicks and input change events being completely different things?

Comment: What is the difference? jQuery does it for you or you do it. jQuery just does a split and a loop and attaches the event. Not going to be a huge difference of performance here.... do what you like.

Comment: Sorry to all for incomprehension. The events that I use are just an example. I replaced the `change` to `hover` (maybe more clear)

Comment: jQuery just attaches the function with both events so the performance is same weather it is this or that approach.

Comment: Just use `.on('click hover'` be proud and call it a day. (Makes no sense to talk about performance at all.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Is not only about perfomance but also code quality and perenity.

Comment: @johannchopin It is a personal opinion on what is better.

Comment: One difference is that you use one instead of two callbacks. If your callback functions are very similar it makes sense to use one .on with multiple events and use a little bit of case-ing in the callback. If your callback functions are very dissimilar you can save a lot of case-ing by simply using two .on functions with wholy different callbacks and end up being more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of **performance**, it is pretty much the same. The native javascript method which jQuery calls is [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which only accepts 1 event as an argument. Whether jQuery likes it or not, adding many event listeners requires calling `addEventListener` once for each listener. See for yourself:

1. Create a new file called `index.html` like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cart">cart</div>
    <script>
        $( "#cart" ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", function( event ) {
          $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Open it with a browser. Go to your browser developer tools (example below is for Chrome), find the `jquery.js` file and place a breakpoint on line 5039:

[image]

3. Reload the page and watch the debugger.

It will go to the breakpoint exactly twice, once for each event you want to listen to. If you change the script tag like this:

```js
$( "#cart" ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave click focus blur", function( event ) {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

It will now pass the breakpoint 5 times, as expected.

Essentially, this jQuery code:

```js
$('#cart').on("mouseenter mouseleave", myCallback);
```

is equivalent to

```js
$('#cart').on("mouseenter", myCallback);
$('#cart').on("mouseleave", myCallback);
```

is equivalent to:

```js
document.getElementById('cart').addEventListener("mouseenter", myCallback);
document.getElementById('cart').addEventListener("mouseleave", myCallback);
```

**Conclusion:** Use whatever pleases you aesthetically.